# What did I do wrong with my URL?

Tags: django, django-urls

Simple question.  Reading the docs, I'm having trouble understanding the syntax in the URLs.

```
(r'^accounts/(?P<username>)/(listview)/$')
```

What did I do wrong here?  Note, username is a variable whereas listview is not.  This should be setup so the enduser can go to /accounts/ben/listview/ and view their profile in a list view.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should do `(r'^accounts/(?P<username>)/listview/$')`, I see no need to parenthesize the `listview` bit if its not a variable.

Answer (score 1):

you need

```
(r'^accounts/(?P<username>[^\/]*)/listview/$')
```

`[^\/]*` means everything except `/`.

`listview` can stay static since it doesnot change.

Answer (score 0):

You need regex in you url to catch your `username` like this:

```
r'^accounts/(?P<username>.*)/(listview)/$'
```